# Why do widgets update simultaneously when assigned to the same data source?

Tags: winforms

I have a very basic question about Windows Forms datasources.

If I assign the same object data source to a combobox and a listbox on the same form I observe interesting UI behavior: when I change the item in a combobox (or listbox) the other control selects the same item.

I have no extra code for this UI behavior so I wonder how it works.

```
 var persons = new List<Person>
                              {
                                  new Person {Id = 1, Age = 10, Name = "Alex"},
                                  new Person {Id = 2, Age = 12, Name = "Boris"},                                 
                              };

   //     ListBox 
   lbPersons.DisplayMember = "Name";           
   lbPersons.DataSource = persons;

    //    ComboBox
    cbPersons.DisplayMember = "Name";
    cbPersons.DataSource = persons;
```

Please, explain how a control's selected item is changed synchronously?

Answer (score 1):

I have found some similar problems on the web.  I don't fully understand how this works, but I will give my best shot at it:

When you have a bind multiple controls to the same datasource, they use the same bindingcontext.  Therefore, switching the selected item on one control will change the the selected item on the other control.

Instead when you bind the datasources, give each one a new BindingContext:

```
lbPersons.DisplayMember = "Name";           
lbPersons.DataSource = persons;
lbPersons.BindingContext = new BindingContext();

cbPersons.DisplayMember = "Name";
cbPersons.DataSource = persons; 
cbPersons.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
```

I found this info in a forum (link below) where they confirm the issue and have a solution.  I need to do more reading on this, but more info can be found in the msdn at:

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/850851-multiple-controls-bound-same-data-source
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingcontext.aspx

EDIT as per:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bindingcontext(v=vs.71).aspx

> The BindingContext object of a Control is used to return a single
>   BindingManagerBase object for all data-bound controls contained by the
>   Control. The BindingManagerBase object keeps all controls that are
>   bound to the same data source synchronized. For example, setting the
>   Position property of the BindingManagerBase specifies the item in the
>   underlying list that all data-bound controls point to.

Also:

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingcontext.bindingcontext(v=vs.71).aspx)

> For example, if you have two BindingManagerBase objects (from two
>   different BindingContext objects), you can set the Position properties
>   of each BindingManagerBase to different values causing each set of
>   data-bound controls will display different values from the same data
>   source.

Comment: It looks like (but I'm not sure) that there is 'a manager' behind the curtains that control DataSource value assigned for all controls. 'manager' tracks all selectedItems changed events and changes SelectedItems for controls that have the same DataSource value assigned. Who knows what is it for and how can it can be disabled for the whole application.

Comment: @AndrewFlorko see my edit.  Does the code above not fix the problem?